# Parsing a table tag by HtmlAgilityPack goes wrong

Tags: c#, html, html-table, html-agility-pack

I have a webpage with table and I want to get all the rows, but when I download it, I get a strange table, with one `<tr>` and many of `</tr>`, and so I can't parse it. What can I do?

My code:

```
  WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
  wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
  wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
  wb.Navigate(link);
  while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }
  string htmlDoc = wb.DocumentText;

  doc.LoadHtml(htmlDoc);

  nodesHtml = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");
```

But instead to get all the rows in `nodesHtml` , I get just one row. The strange thing is that in real browser like FF the html tags looks good, but when downloading the page - the html goes wrong.

Here is the link: http://www.lre.com/test/searchresultx.asp?id=19

Comment: Could you provide us the HTML code you are obtaining (or at least the page) for us to test?

Answer (score 1):

This goes wrong due to the HTML of the page being quite non-compliant,
have a look at the result given by [w3c's validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.lre.com/test/searchresultx.asp?id=19&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)  and you'll
see there's heaps of `tr` and `td` with closure issues.

My advice is either to run the HTML through [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or play around with HTMLAgilityPack's
parsing settings.